# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "18446744073709551615"

Tags: java, eclipse

first of all.. If there is missing some information just ask and I will give the needed input.

I have a .json file on my Desktop, and now I have to use java and have to extract values out of the .json file.
This is my task: **write a script which extract the value
*“automatic -> kernel -> release”*
out of the attached json file.

example: output:

3.16.0-5-amd64**

The json file has 27k+ lines, I don't know if this **can** be a problem or not.

the .json file includes this:

```
   1 {
   2   “results”: 3,
   3   “rows”: [
   4     {
   5   “name”: “test”,
   6   “chef_environment”: “office”,
   7   “json_class”: “Chef::Node”,
   8   “automatic”: {
   9     “nginx”: {
  10       “version”: null,
  11       “configure_arguments”: [
  12
  13       ],
  14       “prefix”: null,
  15       “conf_path”: null
  16     },
.....
  98 “kernel”: {
  99 “name”: “Linux”,
 100 “release”: “3.16.0-5-amd64"
```

And this is my code now:

```
package json;

import java.io.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class json {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        try {
            Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\admin-elias\\Desktop\\nginx.json"));
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

            String automatic = (String) jsonObject.get("automatic");
            String kernel = (String) jsonObject.get("kernel");
            JSONArray release = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("release");

            System.out.println("automatic: "+automatic);
            System.out.println("kernel: "+kernel);
            System.out.println("release: "+release);
            ;



            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    } 
}
```

When I try to run the program, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "18446744073709551615"
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.base/java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:692)
    at java.base/java.lang.Long.valueOf(Long.java:1144)
    at org.json.simple.parser.Yylex.yylex(Yylex.java:660)
    at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.nextToken(JSONParser.java:269)
    at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:118)
    at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:92)
    at json.json.main(json.java:18)
```

What am I doing wrong? I am relatively new to java and I need to get this program running so every suggestion or help would be very nice. :)

**Edit:**

I finally got my code which works just perfectly:

```
public class json {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try {
            JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(new FileReader("filename"));
            Gson gson = new Gson();

            JsonElement json = gson.fromJson(jsonReader, JsonElement.class);

            //JsonElement json = new JsonParser().parse(jsonString);

            JsonArray array = json.getAsJsonObject().get("rows").getAsJsonArray();
            int length = array.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                System.out.println(array.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("automatic").getAsJsonObject().get("kernel").getAsJsonObject().get("release").getAsString());
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: this number 18446744073709551615 does not fit into a long

Comment: Gson library supports big integers out of the box. Is it possible for you to use Gson instead of simple parser? https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.5

Comment: Well @PatrickDorn Then I guess I have to write a complete new code? Haven't used Gson yet but maybe it's worth giving it a try.

Comment: Shouldn't be too hard. Gson supports FileReader as input and has its own com.google.gson.JsonObject and com.google.gson.JsonArray classes. For parsing: JsonObject obj = gson.fromJson(fileReader, JsonObject.class);

Comment: Okay cool @PatrickDorn thank you for the help, I will try that out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value

```
18446744073709551615
```

exceeds the [maximum value of a `long`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#MAX_VALUE):

```
9223372036854775807
```

You should parse it into a `BigInteger` instead.

Comment: Okay, that's good to know. How can I parse into a BigInteger? What do I have to change in my code?

Comment: Well ... According to ["exceeding LONG.MAX_VALUE in JSON Simple parser"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24064028/exceeding-long-max-value-in-json-simple-parser) this does not seem to be possible with JSON Simple. So you must look for another parser.

Comment: Okay.. well.. I will try, thank you :)

Comment: @Ch0p, Can you please assist me in declaring the 18446744073709551615 which 2^64 - 1 value in Java?

Answer (score 0):

it's trying to parse the value as an integer / long and it's outside the range

18446744073709551616 = 2^64 - 1

Integer.MAX_VALUE = 2^31 - 1

Long.MAX_VALUE = 2^63 - 1

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. But what can I change in my code to avoid this problem?

Comment: are you using org.json.simple?

Comment: Yes, as you can already see in my imports at the top :)

Comment: try to use org.json.JSONObject instead of org.json.simple.JSONObject . it's 2 different libraries

Comment: Okay, did that, but the error still remains :/

Comment: Do you have more information? which variable you trying to set? did you post all the code?

Comment: Yes, the code here is the exact same as in my eclipse. Well I noticed that the error slightly changed. the last line of the error `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "18446744073709551615"....at json.json.main(json.java:18)` has changed to `at json.json.main(json.java:17)`

Comment: So I guess it's something at line 17 which is this:    `Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\admin-elias\\Desktop\\nginx.json"));`

Comment: Try change the list object value to one value. “automatic”: "1"